# Basic mapped tuple type example?

Tags: typescript, tuples, mapped-types

How can you map one tuple type to another in typescript?

This question has been asked countless times in many contexts but they all seem to be for specific use-cases or else have subtle bugs.

Can someone provide a simple, correct, general example?

#### Related Questions

- [How to 'map' a Tuple to another Tuple type in Typescript 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672504/how-to-map-a-tuple-to-another-tuple-type-in-typescript-3-0)
- [Why are Typescript Mapped Tuple Types behaving differently when supplying Generic type vs direct type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64138789/why-are-typescript-mapped-tuple-types-behaving-differently-when-supplying-generi)
- [Is Typescript 4.0+ capable of functions using mapped variatic tuple types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64519489/is-typescript-4-0-capable-of-functions-using-mapped-variatic-tuple-types)
- [Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091118/mapping-tuple-typed-value-to-different-tuple-typed-value-without-casts)
- [Can a mapped tuple preserve the length and ordering of typed entries in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70412740/can-a-mapped-tuple-preserve-the-length-and-ordering-of-typed-entries-in-typescri)
- [Issue around Mapped Tuple Types with type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363430/issue-around-mapped-tuple-types-with-type-inference)
- [How to map a typescript tuple into a new tuple using Array.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335982/how-to-map-a-typescript-tuple-into-a-new-tuple-using-array-map)
- [TypeScript generic map variadic tuple values to nested mapped type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867854/typescript-generic-map-variadic-tuple-values-to-nested-mapped-type)
- [Why Typescript Mapped tuple types shows all options in AutoCompletion/Intellisense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221886/why-typescript-mapped-tuple-types-shows-all-options-in-autocompletion-intellisen)
- [Extending (mapped) tuple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55667014/extending-mapped-tuple-types)
- [How to map & index into tuple types that is generically spread in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70736753/how-to-map-index-into-tuple-types-that-is-generically-spread-in-typescript)
- [How to use array.map with tuples in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913193/how-to-use-array-map-with-tuples-in-typescript)
- [Extracting types and returning a mapped tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68384050/extracting-types-and-returning-a-mapped-tuple-type)
- [Can a function return a mapped tuple without noUncheckedIndexedAccess errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66620039/can-a-function-return-a-mapped-tuple-without-nouncheckedindexedaccess-errors)
- [typescript mapped tuple lookup types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53242568/typescript-mapped-tuple-lookup-types)
- [How can you generate a mapped type that is a tuple type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665271/how-can-you-generate-a-mapped-type-that-is-a-tuple-type)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to convert over a generic type parameter not a specific type!

```
type Original = [number, string, Date]
type Converter<T> = T | undefined

type ConvertArray<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Converter<T[K]> }
type Final = ConvertArray<Original>


const fine: Final = [1, 'a', undefined]
const causesError: Final = ['a', 'a', 'a']
const alsoFine = fine.map(val => val)
const doubleLength = fine.length * 2
function fineFunc([num, str, date]: Final) {}
fineFunc(fine)
fineFunc(['a', 'a', 'a']) // error (correctly)

// If you don't use the generic intermediate step:
type WrongFinal = { [K in keyof Original]: Converter<Original[K]>}
const seemsOkRight: WrongFinal = [1, 'a', new Date()]
const actuallyWontWork = seemsOkRight.length * 2 // <- Error!!
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: But that's *not* a mapped tuple type; the resulting type isn't a tuple at all.  You don't need to exclude non-index keys; see [this version of your code](https://tsplay.dev/wOP0lN).  That's the whole point of [support for mapped tuple/array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  Can you [edit] or clarify?

Comment: @jcalz I added playground link explaining why you want to exclude non-index keys and an example of how to add array methods back in

Comment: If you have an explanation it should be in plain text in the answer itself in addition to any external link like a playground.  Do you acknowledge that the output type you’re generating is not a tuple?  I don’t see that explicitly mentioned anywhere here.

Comment: @jcalz I removed the non-tuple answer and put the explanation directly in the text

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself, the `Final` type isn't a real tuple type.  An actual tuple type would be `[Converter<number>, Converter<string>, Converter<Date>]` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1ylkw).  If you want to get a true tuple type out of a mapped type, you need to do it over a generic type parameter and not a specific type (at least until a fix for https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995 ever shows up). I hope that you will at least acknowledge that a type like `{0: number} & number[]` is not a true tuple type like `[number]` is.

Comment: Thank you so much @jca -- that is way better. I updated the answer.